# Galois group of characteristic polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $A$ be a square matrix with rational entries.

Let $p$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Let $G$ be the Galois group of $p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Just out of curiosity: Can anything general be said about $G$ merely in terms of $A$?

Comment: You mean to say something about the *structure* of $G$? Probably not in general, as @PedroTamaroff says, but if the matrix has a power equal to the identity, then the Galois group will be cyclic, won’t it?

Comment: Yes (to me, group = group structure up to isomorphism)